# How do I ensure that Javascript's "this" will refer to the object when using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, this, settimeout

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>What is 'this'?</title>
<script>
function Obj(){
    log('Obj instantiated');
}
Obj.prototype.foo = function (){
    log('foo() says:');
    log(this);
}
Obj.prototype.bar = function (){
    log('bar() was triggered');
    setTimeout(this.foo,300);
}
function log(v){console.log(v)}
var obj = new Obj();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="obj.foo()">Foo</button>
    <button onclick="obj.bar()">Bar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the console output:

```
Obj instantiated
foo() says:
Obj {foo: function, bar: function}
bar() was triggered
foo() says:
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
```

So when it calls obj.foo from the setTimeout, 'this' changes ownership to the Window.  How do I prevent that or properly work with that behavior?

Thanks

Comment: ['The "this" problem' on MDN's `setTimeout` documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem)

Comment: @Popnoodles that didn't do it for me.  Worked just the same as before.  Bind is the answer I needed but thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `.bind` call.

```
setTimeout(this.foo.bind(this),300);
```

Not all browsers support it, but there is a shim on MDN and Underscore has `_.bind(...)` as well

Answer (score 3):

The answers using `bind` are the best, most modern way, of handling this.  But if you have to support older environments and don't want to shim `Function.prototype.bind`, then you could also do it like this:

```
Obj.prototype.bar = function (){
    log('bar() was triggered');
    var ob = this;
    setTimeout(function() {ob.foo();}, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bind method like this

```
setTimeout(this.foo.bind(this),300);
```