# How to use setTimeout in a Vue.js method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I use the `setTimeout()` function in a Vue.js method?

I have already tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
fetchHole: function () { 
    //get data
},

addHole: function () {
    //my query add new
    setTimeout(function () { this.fetchHole() }, 1000)
},
```

I get this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: this.fetchHole is not a function`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ensure that Javascript's "this" will refer to the object when using setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873596/how-do-i-ensure-that-javascripts-this-will-refer-to-the-object-when-using-set)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this: `setTimeout(this.fetchHole, 1000)` because `this` in anonymous function is attached to that anonymous function not to your main function

Answer (score 79):

Add a `bind()` call to your function declaration:

```
setTimeout(function () { this.fetchHole() }.bind(this), 1000)
```

so that your Vue component's `this` is accessible within the function.

<sup>Side note: @nospor's accepted answer is cleaner in this particular situation. The `bind` approach is a bit more generalized - very useful if you want to do an anonymous function, for example.</sup>

Comment: this answer is more complete because it allows multi-line functions without defining another function in the component methods

Answer (score 61):

The classic issue with contextual `this` in JavaScript.

The following part of code shows an easy solution - if you are using ES6 with Vuejs (default config with vuecli y babel). Use an arrow function

```
setTimeout(()=>{
   this.yourMethod()
},1000);
```

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The `this` value of
>   the enclosing lexical scope is used;

[Arrow functions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: **this** is how you do it

Answer (score 5):

I think this works too.

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function () { self.fetchHole() } , 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call recursive with TimeOut:

```
    save: function () {
      this.progressToProced = 0
      this.progress()          
    },
    progress: function () {
      if (this.progressToProced < 100) {
        this.progressToProced++
        setTimeout(function () { this.progress() }.bind(this), 100)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try :

```js
addHole:function(){
  let vm = this
  setTimeout(function(){vm.fetchHole()}, 1000)
}
```