# How to evaluate a function containing settimeout for each item in an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, time, iife

I have a basic understanding of setTimeout and why it is necessary to use immediately invoked functions to do what it says in my questions title.  My attempt doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do, however.  `Self.instruct` sets a reactive data element so that the message should be displayed to the screen.  Only the last elements of each object-array end up being displayed.

```
    export default {
         name: 'hello',
         props: ['tolearn'],
         data () {
         return {
             message: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
             toLearn: {},
             instruct: ''
         }
         },
         methods: {
    showSlow: function(){
         var self = this;
         categoriesRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
         var val = snapshot.val();
         var sysName = val.name;
         var sysChildren = val.children;
         console.log(Object.keys(val.children) + " are the aspect names")

         sysChildren.forEach(function(aspect){
             (function(aspect){
             //self.instruct = aspect.name + ' is one aspect of ' + sysName + '.';         
             setTimeout(function(){
                 aspect.children.forEach(function(group){

                 (function(group){

                     //self.instruct = aspect.name + ' contains the group ' + group.name + '.';
                     setTimeout(function(){
                     group.children.forEach(function(item){

                         (function(item){
                         console.log(item.name + ' is being considered')


   self.instruct = group.name + ' contains the item ' + item.name + '.';
                     setTimeout(function(){
                         self.instruct = '';
                     }.bind(self), 800)
                     })(item)                        
                 })                          
                 }.bind(self), 100)
             })(group)               
             })                      
         }.bind(self), 1500)
         })(aspect)
     })
     })
     }
     }
 }
```

basically, `val` taken from the snapshot is a json tree structure 3 levels deep, each level containing a `name` and a `children` property.

The `console.log` outputs several 'itemname is being considered' messages at once when the program is finished running.

Can anyone help me figure out how to write this correctly so that all of the tree's elements are displayed?  Somehow my IIFE's aren't enough.

Comment: Not relevant for your question, but all your `.bind(self)` calls are redundant as you don't access `this` in your callbacks anyway

Comment: @amiramw  the whole function is a method on a Vue object that self is refering to.  It seems to work -- or the self.instruct is being updated, at least.

Comment: The code will work also without the bind calls. Self is taken from the scope, bind affect the value of this. But you don't use this at all so it is redundant.

Comment: @amiramw  It definitely doesn't work without the bind calls.   The function is able to access `data.instruct` because it gets a pointer to the Vue object to use as 'this' (I've added the rest of the code to the question so you can see).  I originally had it without the bind calls, and only added them after seeing this answer, which made the code work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465289/how-to-set-timeout-in-a-vuejs-method

Comment: In this answer there is a use of this. In your code I don't see any use of this...

Comment: @amiramw   var self=this  at beginning of function

Comment: You need bind to affect the this binding inside the function. Not outside.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that all your delayed functions are going to be executed at the same time.

If you have n children then after 1500 ms you are going to have n calls very close to one another. The other `setTimeout` calls has the same behavior.

It actually make sense that the last element only take effect.

Comment: But shouldn't at least the lowest level be executed with waits between?  I tried it with commenting out everything except the last function's updates of self.instructions, and it still only dispays the last item.

Comment: If you want wait betweens you should try recursively call setTimout. Otherwise you are scheduling a lot of functions to execute at the same time