# How to commit to store within a SetTimeOut in VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, timeout

I am making an app in Laravel using Vue.js. I would like to wait two seconds when a method is triggered and then execute a store action. However, when I implement this I receive an error.

Here is my code:

```js
.listen('TeamLeaving', e => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    axios.get('/api/team/' + e.team.id + '/pulse').then(response => {
      if (response.data === 0) {
        // here is where it messes up
        this.$store.commit('team/REMOVE_TEAM', e.team)
      }
    })
  }, 2000)

  // this.$store.commit('team/REMOVE_TEAM', e.team);
})
```

However I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'commit' of undefined
```

When I do the commit outside of the `setTimeout` it works just fine. So I am assuming there is a problem inside the `setTimeout`. Could someone help me maneuver this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post might help you: [how to set timeout in a vueJs method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465289/how-to-set-timeout-in-a-vuejs-method/37465651)

The important bit:

> `this` in anonymous function is attached to that anonymous function
>   not to your main function

You can try this:

```
.listen('TeamLeaving', (e) => {
                    let vm = this;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        axios.get('/api/team/'+ e.team.id + '/pulse')
                            .then(response => {

                                if (response.data === 0) {
                                    //here is where it messes up
                                    vm.$store.commit('team/REMOVE_TEAM', e.team)
                                }
                            });


                    }, 2000);

                    // this.$store.commit('team/REMOVE_TEAM', e.team);

                });
```