# How to hide elemets after certain time in vue?

Tags: vue.js, settimeout

I'm doing an internet-shop app in vue and when I add to cart certain products, I need to show a text, that will show ,that element is added to cart. But afer some time, I need to hide the text. How can I do that?
,when you click on Add to cart button,this text shows up.
added to cart!

In  mounted I tried this:

```
   mounted() {
   setTimeout(()=>{
    this.isAdded=false
      },1000)
}
```

but nothing works, text still appears there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465289/how-to-set-timeout-in-a-vuejs-method/37465651

Comment: You can use a toast library for this purpose. Here is one for vue https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toast-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      isAdded: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.isAdded = true
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.isAdded = false
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="add">add</button>
  <h1 v-if="isAdded">
    added
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much! I just needed to add this ajax script and everyting worked!